# Need to place Random images (on page refreshed/reloaded) on Wordpress header banner

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Currently i using a header banner with theme option, where my banner code looks like

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" alt="" title="" /></a>
```

that i can use a single image in my above banner.

But now my advertiser want me to use two images instead of one (advertise link remain same), where images will be change randomly each time page is loaded/refreshed.

Please, help me on this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Using PHP will be a better option here than JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

using php rand(1,2); function that return 1 or 2 , then using this random value to show image url on img src.
this may help

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/random-imagelogo-on-header